# Archiving whole website while keeping its URLs working

Tags: http

I am looking for a tool which would allow me to archive my website to GitHub Pages. I was looking into using `wget` and `httrack` which do a good job for a local mirror which I can open in a browser, but the issue is that they break URLs and so external links to my website would break if I just mirror the website and replace it with GitHub pages. I want to mirror the website into bunch of files I upload to GitHub Pages and then point the domain name there.

I think I want an alternative to `wget`'s `--adjust-extension` which would make all downloaded HTML URLs without file extension instead into its own directory as `index.html`. I would want that `/foo/bar` URL gets downloaded into `/foo/bar/index.html`, so that when you then open `/foo/bar` in a browser, standard HTTP servers (and GitHub Pages) redirect to `/foo/bar/index.html`. Is there such a tool which would do something like this?

So with this there would be an extra redirect to new location, but all existing inbound links from other sites to archived website would continue to work.